# Username change in @-notifications

Tags: feature-request

math.stackexchange.com has a feature where we can notify users in the comments e.g. @Euler or @Klein. However I have noticed that when a user changes his name from say Euler to Gauss, any existing tag @Euler does not change to @Gauss.

I understand facebook has this feature, can it be implemented in here? It would be useful because when I am going through posts where some users have changed names, I find it frustrating sometimes when trying to understand the genealogy of the comments posted.

Comment: +1 I asked for this back a while over at [meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53419/146482) with no official reply though

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This feature-request has been issued on [meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53419/auto-expand-username-in-comments-to-keep-the-username-up-to-date). While I don't know the prospects for getting this implemented, this is to let you know that it has been escalated to the network level and shows up in the queue of features to consider for implementation.